# Alinamento de elementos dentro de um DIV

Tags: css, bootstrap-3

Como faço para alinhar itens dentro de um div conforme seguinte imagem;
[inserir a descrição da imagem aqui](https://i.stack.imgur.com/d0XzR.png)

Código HTML

```
<div class="birthday-row" data-birthday-item=""   >
    <div class="birthday-col-1"  >
        <a href="#" target="_black">
            <img style="height:44px;width:44px;" class="img-radius" src=#">
        </a>
    </div>  
    <div class="birthday-col-2">
        <h4 class="data-birthday ">
                01/12 
        </h4>   
        <h3 class="name-birthday">
            <a href="#">
            Dev Junior 
            </a>
        </h3>
        <p class="depUni row">  
        ANALISTA 
        </p>
    </div>
</div>
```

CSS

```
.birthday-row{
   align-items: baseline;
    align-items: center  ;
    width: 100%  ;
    padding: 10px  ;
}

.birthday-col-2 , .birthday-col-1{
   display: flex;       
}
```

Comment: o que já tentou fazer? coloquei na pergunta tbm o css

Comment: @RicardoPontual acrescentei o css,mas tentei resolver o problema apenas com grid system do bootstrap usando .row ,mas não ficou conforme resultado esperado.

Comment: @RafaelLuz você está usando `bootstrap` em algum lugar do seu código ou apenas foi marcado a `tag` errada na sua pergunta?

Comment: @William estou usando bootstrap